# Foreach loops in an array with JSON

Tags: php, json

I've got this PHP code

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('comments.json');
    $decode = json_decode($json);
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    foreach($decode->comments as $key)
    {
        var_dump(array(
            $key->name,
            $key->email,
            $key->comment
        ));
    }
    $decode->comments = array(array('name'=>$name, 'email'=>$email, 'comment'=>$comment));
    $encode = json_encode($decode,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    file_put_contents('comments.json',$encode);
?>
```

It kind of works, it sets the current stuff in the JSON file to what its told to in this piece of PHP code. Instead of this, I want the PHP code to add on to the JSON that is already existing.

This is the JSON file.

```
  {
        "comments": {
            "0": {
                "name": "123",
                "email": "123",
                "comment": "123"
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: You're nearly there. Just append to the `$decode->comments` using `$decode->comments[] = ...` instead of wiping it out entirely using `$decode->comments = ...`

Comment: It comes up with the error `'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\lewios\addcomment.php on line 15` =/

Comment: Ah, use `$decode = json_decode($json, true);` so you're working with an associative array and change all OOP instances of `$decode->comments` to `$decode['comments']` (and `$key['name']`, etc...)

Comment: You're welcome. I added a more detailed answer for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a boolean `true` so you get an associative array instead of an object-based decode:

```
$json = file_get_contents('comments.json', true);
```

Change all of your OOP references to associative array style:

```
foreach($decode['comments'] as $key)
{
    var_dump($key); // Declaring a whole new array isn't really needed here
}
```

Append to the decoded JSON array using the `[]` syntax:

```
$decode['comments'][] = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'comment' => $comment,
);
```

Re-encode and return the resulting JSON:

```
$encode = json_encode($decode, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
file_put_contents('comments.json',$encode);
```